# R: Multivariate Wilcoxon test

Tags: r, stat

I have a dataset with 20 variables, and 81 observations from two groups.
I want to test whether the two groups are different.

The observations are not normal within each group so I must do a non parametric test.

If I had just one variable, I would do a wilcoxon test (wilcox.test in R).
But I have 20 variables, and I don't want to make 20 wilcox.test because I want to study  the data as a whole.

I thought I could find a multivariate wilcoxon test, which I did: the function `mWilcoxonTest` from `DepthProc` package.

It is presumably easy to run and I did:
`mWilcoxonTest(data1[,c(3:22)], data2[,c(3:22)])`

My `data1`  and `data2` datasets contain 7 and 74 observations respectively,  and the 20 variables are found in columns 3 to 22.

But unfortunately, every time I run this command, the results are different:

```
W = 200, p-value = 0.3253
W = 225, p-value = 0.5733
etc.
```

This doesn't make any sense!!

So  (1) Do you understand what is going on?

Or (2) do you know another way to do this test in R?

Thanks!